# ml5 (ml5.js): How do I add my own data to the KNN classifier?

Tags: javascript, knn, p5.js

Trying to use the ml5 (ml5js.org) KNN classifier on a game I made. But I don't understand how to add my own data to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Getting Started with ml5.js</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.1.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    let grid = [
      [1, 2],
      [3, 4]
    ];
    let knnClassifier = ml5.KNNClassifier();

    console.log('trying to add to classifier');
    addExample('left');

    function addExample(label) {
      knnClassifier.addExample(grid, label);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected that code to add to the classifier instead Im getting an error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

The ml5 page has a KNN classifier example where they convert their data in the following way.

```
  // Convert poses results to a 2d array [[score0, x0, y0],...,[score16, x16, y16]]
  const poseArray = poses[0].pose.keypoints.map(p => [p.score, p.position.x, p.position.y]);
```

Unsure but I think their data looks something like:

```
{
    "score": 0.32371445304906,
    "keypoints": [ { "position": { "x": 301.42237830162, "y": 177.69162777066 }, "score": 0.99799561500549 },...
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed the last vertion, so change part of the link:
ml5@0.1.3
to
ml5@0.3.0

And it works.